# Difference in "sourcing" from a file in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

What is the difference between the following two commands to source a file and then print the `env` variables?

```
sh -c . envvars.sh; env
```

And:

```
./envvars.sh; env
```

More specifically, what do the following do:

```
". envvars.sh" vs. "./envvars.sh"
```

And:

```
"sh -c envvars.sh" and "./envvars.sh"
```

Comment: Did you already read https://ss64.com/bash/source.html by any chance? It explains what the difference is between sourcing and just executing the script.

Comment: `sh -c . envvars.sh` doesn't even pass `envvars.sh` as an argument to `.`; it *completely ignores* that argument, and thus causes `.` to fail with a usage error. You probably meant `sh -c '. envvars.sh'`; the quoting is not optional.